# Pandas google analytics API - how to switch account?

Tags: python, api, pandas, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a Google Analytics account link to several websites.
I set up GA api for pandas following http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/pandas-google-analytics.html
But I did not understand how can I switch from a website to an other website.

I'm connecting to GA through python using:

```
  temp_df = ga.read_ga(metrics,
                  dimensions=dimensions,
                  start_date=start_date,
                  end_date=end_date,
                  index_col=0,
                  filters=filters,
                  start_index=start_index
                )
```

But how can I change the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the `account_id`, `property_id` and `profile_id` parameters:

```
temp_df = ga.read_ga(metrics,
              dimensions=dimensions,
              start_date=start_date,
              end_date=end_date,
              index_col=0,
              filters=filters,
              account_id=account,
              property_id=property,
              profile_id=profile,
              start_index=start_index)
```

More documentation can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html#remote-data-ga

I've found it useful to package up all my account information into a separate JSON file:

```
{
    "site1": {
        "acct": "123456",
        "prop": "UA-123456-1",
        "view": "098345983"
    },
    "site2": {
        "acct": "987654",
        "prop": "UA-987654-1",
        "view": "398475987"
    },
    "site3": {
        "acct": "456789",
        "prop": "UA-456789-1",
        "view": "938745876"
    }
}
```

Then, import those accounts into my script like this:

```
import json

# p as path, gc as google analytics credentials
with open('/Path/To/Your/JSON/Goes/Here/google_analytics_accounts.json') as p:
    gc = json.load(p)
    p.close()
```

So that I can then use whichever credentials I need when reading Google Analytics to a DataFrame:

```
temp_df = ga.read_ga(metrics,
              dimensions=dimensions,
              start_date=start_date,
              end_date=end_date,
              index_col=0,
              filters=filters,
              account_id=gc['site1']['acct'],
              property_id=gc['site1']['prop'],
              profile_id=gc['site1']['view'],
              start_index=start_index)
```